# MPI_Reduce pointers

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

Could you please help me with MPI_Reduce. I am getting error like this

```
In: PMI_Abort(1, Fatal error in PMPI_Reduce:
Internal MPI error!, error stack: 
PMPI_Reduce(1284)....................: MPI_Reduce(sbuf=0x7fffcd0d0ae0, rbuf=0x7fffcd0d0af0, count=400, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, root=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Reduce_impl(1090)...............: 
MPIR_Reduce_MV2(1173)................: 
MPIR_Reduce_two_level_helper_MV2(887): 
MPIR_Reduce_binomial_MV2(119)........: 
MPIR_Localcopy(386)..................: memcpy arguments alias each other, dst=0x7fffcd0d0af0 src=0x7fffcd0d0ae0 len=3200
)
```

These are the codes
for all processes

```
#define binsperdegree 4
#define totaldegrees 64

long int TotalCountDD;
long int tDD;

int nr_of_bins = binsperdegree*totaldegrees;  
int hgram_size = nr_of_bins+1;

long int *histogramDD; 
long int *totalDD;
```

for the root process

```
totalDD = (long int *)calloc( tDD, sizeof(long int));
MPI_Reduce(&histogramDD, &totalDD, tDD, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

for non root processes

```
totalDD = (long int *)calloc(tDD , sizeof(long int));
MPI_Reduce(&histogramDD, &totalDD, TotalCountDD, MPI_LONG, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: Do not pass pointers to the pointers but rather pass the pointers themselves, e.g. `MPI_Reduce(histogramDD, totalDD, ...)`. Also the result argument is not used in non-root processes. If you need the value of the reduction in all processes, use `MPI_Allreduce` instead.

Comment: Thanks.
whatdo you mean by "the result argument is not used in non-root processes"

Comment: `MPI_Reduce` has a parameter, `root`, which specifies the rank of the process that is to receive the result of the reduction operaiton. In all other ranks the value of the `recvbuf` argument is simply ignored.

Comment: Just a further clarification if it is not obvious - I wrote that comment because you allocate space for the receive buffer also in the non-root processes. Also note that you have to provide the same elements count in all processes, i.e. `tDD` must equal `TotalCountDD` in your case.